# Use the relation $x^3=y$ to get $\alpha^3 + \beta^3+\gamma^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

I have this equation

$$x^3-x^2-x+0.5=0$$

Now i have to use the relation $x^3=y$ to get $\alpha^3 + \beta^3+\gamma^3$ which will be the roots of the new equation obatained.

I know that i can use many other ways but how to solve by this method

I end up with this

$$y-y^{\frac {2}{3}}-y^{\frac {1}{3}}+0.5=0$$

I can't factor out $y^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Any help is appriciated

Comment: Are $\alpha ,\beta$ and $\gamma$ roots of the given equation?

Comment: yeah they are the roots of the equation

Comment: So let's get this straight. The roots of $x^3 - x^2 -x + 0.5$ are $\alpha^3, \beta^3, \gamma^3$. We want to find $\alpha + \beta + \gamma$ so we make this substitution. Am I right?

Comment: No I want to use this subsitution to make a new equation whose roots are cube of the previous equation roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$y+0.5=y^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
Now cube both sides to get a cubic equation in $y$.
$$\Longrightarrow y^3+1.5 y^2+ 0.75 y+0.125 = y^2+y+3y(y^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}})$$

Now use the first equation again in it.

Comment: I cubed the equation but on the right hand side I get some messy y's with radical power.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Ohhhh thanks :)

Comment: $y^3$ on the lhs not $y$. Please edit.

Comment: Can you tell me a general method of how to solve these kind of questions. You don't have to add details just give a glimpse of it.

Comment: @HVxvejjw, I've corrected now.

Comment: @Harshit Gupta, there is no general method for all problems, but in this particular situation, I would prefer to use the identity $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)((x+y+z)^2-3(xy+yz+zx))$ , since except the required sum, everything else is given to us, and much less calculations are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
Use $$(y +0.5)^3 =y^2 +y+3y^{2 \over 3}.y^{1 \over 3}(y^{2 \over 3}+y^{1 \over 3})$$
Again use

$$ y^{2 \over 3}+y^{1 \over 3}=y+0.5$$
We got 
$$(y+0.5)^3=y^2+y+3y(y+0.5)$$
Solve it into cubic equations . And then you know the formula for sum of roots.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$2x^3+1=2x^2+2x$$

Cubing both sides  $$8(x^3)^3+1^3+3(2x^3)(2x^3+1)=(2x^2+2x)^3=8(x^3)^2+8(x^3)+3(2x^2)(2x)(2x^2+2x)$$

Now  as $x^3=y, 2x^2+2x=2x^3+1=2y+1$

$$8y^3+1+6y(2y+1)=8y^2+8y+12y(2y+1)$$

$$\implies8y^3+y^2(12-8-24)+(\cdots)y+(\cdots)=0$$ whose roots are

$$\alpha^3,\beta^3,\gamma^3$$

Using Vieta's formula $$\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3=-\dfrac{12-8-24}8$$